# Site compromised: ZMEU attack

Tags: mysql, apache, phpmyadmin, web, server

My site has been compromised with ZmEu attacks. In the logs I find suspicious user agents named - ZmEu.

[image]

The site returns 500 internal server error. There are no related error logs in the apache error log.
There are several dummy files all over in my server. I removed all of them.

But still the site is down.

What is the main target for such attacks?(What files are modified and how do I get them back?)

Where should I look to fix the issues?

If anyone has undergone such situation please give your advise.

update: Its wordpress site which is not working. There are other apps in sub directories which are working fine.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1):

You restore from a backup in this situation.

It will be tough to sort through and reverse everything 100%. The hacker could have even changed the modification times on the files, so you'll never be able to tell what has been accessed or not, without combing through every line.

Comment: I fear there's no backup of the current version. Its wordpress site which is not working. There are other apps in sub directories which are working fine.

Comment: You'll need to go in and examine all the code to see if you can notice what's been changed. This will need to be done manually.

Comment: Thanks for the support. What about manually upgrading wordpress(replacing all files)? Will it work? Guess I've to try this.

Comment: You could try that, but it doesn't rule out problems with your database either. I'd start off by just looking at the files... see if anything looks like it isn't supposed to be there. And as you mentioned, have a look at the modification times.